# Get sequences from Pandas dataframe based on index

Tags: pandas, slice

I have Pandas dataframe describing GPS data, where columns represent track index, point index (point position along the track) and lat / lon values (displayed as "xx" for brevity.

```
track point  lat  lon
    1     1   xx   xx
    1     2   xx   xx
    1     3   xx   xx
    2     1   xx   xx
    2     2   xx   xx
    2     3   xx   xx
  ...    ...  ..   ..
```

I would like a way to slice by `track` and then sort by `point`. So far, I do this in a loop, but I wonder if this is the right way (I guess no, because it doesn't seem efficient):

```
trks = getDataframe()  //dataframe is created elsewhere
tracks = []            //this is what I want: some sequence of individual tracks
for trk in sorted(set(trks.trk)):
    track = trks[(trks.track==trk)
    track.sort(columns='point')
    tracks.append(track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby`:

```
tracks = [grp.sort(['point']) for key, grp in trks.groupby(['track'])]
```

---

For example,

```
In [236]: trks = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

In [237]: trks
Out[237]: 
   track  point lat lon
0      1      2  xx  xx
1      1      3  xx  xx
2      1      1  xx  xx
3      2      1  xx  xx
4      2      3  xx  xx
5      2      2  xx  xx

In [239]: for key, grp in trks.groupby(['track']):
   .....:     print(grp.sort(['point']))
   .....:     
   track  point lat lon
2      1      1  xx  xx
0      1      2  xx  xx
1      1      3  xx  xx
   track  point lat lon
3      2      1  xx  xx
5      2      2  xx  xx
4      2      3  xx  xx
```

---

Note that it is usually more efficient to keep all the data in one DataFrame. Once you break up the DataFrame into a list of smaller pieces, then whenever you want to do something to all the frames, you have to use a Python loop. This tends to slow down the calculation. You'll usually do better if you can find a way to express your calculation as something applied to the DataFrame as a whole.